# Rails 3 multisite (Assocation with id )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm working on a new rails project which involves running multiple website from a single rails installation. I am confuse on how to do the association without nesting the resources.

> note: I am using subdomains so url would be site1.ex.com/photos,
>   site2.ex.com/ramps

For example now I have a site named **site 1** and **site 1** has photos, videos, and ramps. I can do the association by telling rails site has_many :photos, :videos, :ramps(Code is not formatted properly just giving you the idea). Everything works fine including url but here is my problem.

1. site is included in the url which is something I do not want(ex. example.com/sites/1/photos).
2. Association works fine but what if I would like to have parents for the 3 items? Rails suggests you do not nest routes over 1 level deep. 
   [image]

Here is what I would like to do
[image]

1. How can I called the association between site without using nested resources(Can't capture the site_id with album_id for photos)?
2. If album **has_many :photos** and **belongs_to :site** how can I call that in my controller(Any examples)?

Am rails newb so I've added pictures so someone could understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use subdomains, you don't have to use nested resources for `sites`. To find a site:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :find_site_by_subdomain

  def find_site_by_subdomain
    @site = Site.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
  end

end
```

For all the other resources, you nest them not under `Site`but use themselves as the parent (Album/Photos, Videos, Ramps). And in your `AlbumsController` you will want only those that belong to the site with the current subdomain, so you make use of your before_filter from the `ApplicationController` and use the `@site` object:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  …

  def show
    @album = @site.albums.find(params[:id])
  end

  …
end
```

Comment: What if album `has_many :photos` how can I integrate albums, site, and photos into one call or in my controller?

Comment: Make a PhotosController, add a `before_filter :find_album` and make a method called `find_album` in which you call `@album = @site.albums.find(params[:album_id])`. Then in your show method you call `@photo = @album.photos.find(params[:id])`